# Clickable text in textView with multiple colors and events

Tags: java, android, textview, user-experience

I would like to make one **TextView** **clickable** with multiple words which would have different colors and **events** assigned.

eg:

"**@james** loves to play with **#girls**"

**@james**, (green, bold) other event than **#girls**, (yellow).

How to achieve this in easiest way?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html).

Create a SpannableString, with two spans: one for each word you'd like to be colored differently than the rest of the text.

```
String name   = "@james";
String action = " likes to play with ";
String tag    = "#girls";

SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(name + action + tag);
ForegroundColorSpan green      = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN); 
ForegroundColorSpan yellow     = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW); 

builder.setSpan(green,  0, name.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 
builder.setSpan(yellow, 0, name.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 

actionTextView.setText(sb);
```

for the clickable portion of your question, use a [ClickableSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) the same as the ForegroundColorSpan above.

Answer (score 0):

You can set HTML formatted text on The TextView, of course, it doesn't support all HTML tags, but it supports many text formatting tags. You can set html formatted text like this

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
```